# JSONObject - Cannot extract item

Tags: android, json

I got Firebase JSONObject that looks like the one below, and I need to extract ONLY  user ID `["11111.812763462834126346128349.2222"]` and email:

```
{ 
"identities": {
    "apple.com": [
        "11111.812763462834126346128349.2222"
    ],
    "email": [
        "email@yahoo.com"
    ]
  },
"sign_in_provider": "apple.com"
}
```

I can't figure out how to operate with the complex array. None of the examples helped. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: before asking to SO, did you try something?

Comment: I don't think I can technically be able to publish 50-100 variations of everything I tried and all the posts I checked related to this subject. But ... I got it answered by Red-Kal (see below)